# Displays the total number of comments of the logged in user ( $user_id = get_current_user_id(); )

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to see the number of comments entered by the user connected ( `$user_id = get_current_user_id();` ). I have tried this code but it does not work.

```
<?php
global $wpdb, $post, $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
$userId = $current_user->ID;

$where = 'WHERE comment_approved = 1 AND user_id = ' . $userId ;
$comment_count = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT( * ) AS total 
                                 FROM {$wpdb->comments}
                                 {$where}");
echo $comment_count;
?>
```

Do you have any advice? What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `get_comments` function provided by Wordpress to query all comments based on query arguments. Here's your code refactored to use this function:

```php
<?php
global $current_user;

$userId       = $current_user->ID;
$comment_args = [
   'user_id' => $userId,
   // `count` is set to true to return the number of comments per UserID
   'count'   => TRUE
];

echo get_comments( $comment_args );
?>
```

See the docs [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comments/) for full reference on the `get_comments` function.